# Non-intrusive server monitoring software

Tags: monitoring, server

I run a relatively small virtual environment out of my basement for basic services such as web hosting, file serving, and small media center. I try to keep close tabs on the performance of my environment through routine checks, but I also wanted a quick way of knowing whether or not all my services were actually activated.

### What I'm using now

So a few months back, I developed a small bash script that I just called "status.sh". It's probably the ugliest piece of code ever to exist, but it works, so I kept using it.

The program (if you can even call it  that) is structured pretty rudimentarily: it's just a bunch of *if* statements that determine whether an IP responds to either a ping or a netcat TCP probe, and depending on the result, states that service is either "up" or "down."

A single variable, $(hostlist), contains a bunch of the *if*-statement triggers. I designed it that way because I also run a separate script that I've named "networkNotifier.sh," which sends my phone a notification if any of the servers are listed as "down." If I were to temporarily shut one of my servers down, I would be getting endless texts, so I made the $(hostlist) variable to be able to temporarily pull addresses of servers that I know are offline without deleting or commenting out whole blocks of code.

### What I'm looking for

I'm looking for a simplistic server monitor program that only runs ICMP pings and TCP probes to check if a server is responding, and if not, triggers a script.

Please don't recommend anything that requires I install 3rd party software on every one of my servers. I'm looking for something that I can install/run on a dedicated monitoring server that probes the network. I don't need stats like CPU usage or disk usage of each server, just an up/down status.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I realize this is a very old question, but if anyone happened to come across it, I wrote a clean solution to this in Java, and it's all on [Github](https://github.com/TheFuzzyFish/NetStatus) if anyone wants it.